# addSubview in "for loop" with count

Tags: ios, for-loop, subview, addsubview

I have a question about the FOR loop and Subviews. I want to show a different SubView every time the loop runs with a different subview name. The name must be "hoofdstukController" + the i count.

How can i do this? I tried a couple of methods but all crashed the app. This is my loop:

```
_viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    CGRect frame = _scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0; 
    hoofdstukController.view.frame = frame;
    [_scrollView addSubview:hoofdstukController.view];
    [_viewControllers addObject:hoofdstukController];
}
```

Hope anyone can push me in the right direction!

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that? The loop will execute in a few milliseconds, so even if the UI phase were able to act in between - which it isn't because it's happening on another "place" in the runloop - you wouldn't see anything because it's too fast. Are you trying to achieve some kind of visual effect here?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, no it is a slide app that i try to make. Some sort of magazine app. The user can slide trough trough all the viewcontrollers. But i dont want to duplicate the same code 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

You should add all your viewcontrollers to the array first:

```
_viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[_viewControllers addObject:hoofdstukController];
[_viewControllers addObject:hoofdstukController0];
[_viewControllers addObject:hoofdstukController1];
//etc.
```

Then you can loop through that array and add their views as subview. Note that you should also add them as child viewcontrollers of you parent viewcontroller:

Edit: Sorry for the 'i' to work you need to modify it a bit

```
for (UIViewController *vc in _viewControllers)
{
    CGRect frame = _scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0; 
    vc.view.frame = frame;

    [viewControllerHostingTheScrollView addChildViewController:vc];
    [_scrollView addSubview:vc.view];
    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:viewControllerHostingTheScrollView];
}
```

Edit: Sorry for the 'i' to work you need to modify it a bit:

```
int i = 0;
for (UIViewController *vc in _viewControllers)
{
    CGRect frame = _scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * i++;
    frame.origin.y = 0; 
    vc.view.frame = frame;

    [viewControllerHostingTheScrollView addChildViewController:vc];
    [_scrollView addSubview:vc.view];
    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:viewControllerHostingTheScrollView];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! EDIT: i think i got your point now. I will try something out! Thanks for now!

Answer (score 0):

In your code you set frame  `hoofdstukController.view.frame` 10 times in one  hoofdstukController. It take final frame to that (`frame.size.width * i`). Here you have to `alloc` and `init` method every time of for loop run and also  `setTag` for your `hoofdstukController.tag=i`.